# Rasbian WebDav-Client davfs2: Create folder successfully, but files won't

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-4, permissions, share

Dear specialists :) ,

I got a lot of help during the last month from this forum but this time I can't find the right thread.

Problem:
I had connected a WebDav-Connection to the https://dav.mailbox.org successfully simultaneously with Android, Win10, and Raspbian. But surprisingly I can't copy or create files within the WebDav-Folder on the Raspbian-side. I can create and rename a given folder. Deleting them is not possible. On Window10-side everything works as aspected.

For a project, I need an auto-sync "area" between these three devices.

Do you have any hint for me?

Kind regards
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution.

The setting of the my configuration **davfs2.conf** should be so:

```
if_match_bug 1
use_locks 0
cache_size 1
table_size 4096
delay_upload 1
gui_optimize 1
```

Src: https://kb.mailbox.org/display/MBOKBEN/WebDav+for+Linux?beecom.language=en

Kind regards
Daniel

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.